# Argument must be of type X, X given

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, typeerror

Sometimes, I get an exception message:

`Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource::toArray(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php on line 60`

It's a simple controller which

```
return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource::collection(collect([1,2,3]));
```

Running Laravel 10.9

(Most of the time it works. *Sometimes* it fails..)

A little more of the trace:

```
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:60",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php:558",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php:771",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/HigherOrderCollectionProxy.php:59",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php:102",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/JsonResource.php:107",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php:19",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php:134",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php:114",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:888",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:875",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:797",
    "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:141",
    ...
```

---

**Edit:**

This is running on Kubernetes pods.

It's possible that this has to do with some sort of segmentation fault happening on the pod.

Comment: Is that actually what the controller does or can the controllers return be different at times?

Comment: I simplified a little.. but the collection is relatively stable. It's not due to the change in the collection.

Comment: What do you mean "most of time it works, sometime it fails"? In what circumstances does it fail? Did you try to log before returning and check what exactly it's trying to return before exception occurs?